# Is it safe to uninstall flatpak runtimes for apps I no longer have installed?

Tags: flatpak

```
user@ncase:~$ flatpak list
Ref                                                  Options       
org.DolphinEmu.dolphin-emu/x86_64/stable             system,current
org.freedesktop.Platform.GL.nvidia-396-54/x86_64/1.4 system,runtime
org.freedesktop.Platform.ffmpeg/x86_64/1.6           system,runtime
org.freedesktop.Platform/x86_64/1.6                  system,runtime
org.gtk.Gtk3theme.Adapta-Eta/x86_64/3.22             system,runtime
org.kde.Platform/x86_64/5.11                         system,runtime
org.kde.Platform/x86_64/5.9                          system,runtime
user@ncase:~$ flatpak list --app
Ref                                      Options       
org.DolphinEmu.dolphin-emu/x86_64/stable system,current
user@ncase:~$ flatpak uninstall
```

As you can see, I only have 1 flatpak app installed, but I have a lot of flatpak runtimes installed. Are they safe to uninstall, or are they still in use somehow?

Comment: the different runtimes might be there for apps that need specific versions (like some java aps) if you know nothing needs them it is probably safe... if you keep a list of everything, you can always reinstall it if something breaks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To add to [@karel's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1077056/3913110770562):
The command `flatpak uninstall --unused` uninstalls all unneeded runtimes.

Comment: This won't remove pinned packages. I have old, pinned versions of packages. How can I remove or unpin them? Note: I can't just use the package name, I need to include the specific version but can't find info on how to do that.

Answer (score 2):

The six Flatpak runtimes that are installed are being used by the DolphinEmu Flatpak app (org.DolphinEmu.dolphin-emu/x86_64/stable), so it is not safe to uninstall them.

Assuming that you no longer have any Flatpak apps installed it's safe to remove all the installed Flatpak runtimes with a command of the form `flatpak uninstall --runtime ID-of-1st-app ID-of-next-app ID-of-last-app`. These Flatpak runtimes will get automatically reinstalled the next time that you install a Flatpak app from the flathub remote, so it makes sense to not uninstall these Flatpak runtimes unless you are sure that you don't want to install any more Flatpak apps.