# Uninstall a flatpak software installations

Tags: 18.04, uninstall, flatpak

I just wanted to install on my Ubuntu 18 Notes-up by following this article https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/11/notes-up-markdown-editor-for-linux

So I did:

```
sudo flatpak install --from https://flathub.org/repo/appstream/com.github.philip_scott.notes-up.flatpakref
The remote 'flathub', refered to by 'com.github.philip_scott.notes-up' at location https://dl.flathub.org/repo/ contains additional applications.
Should the remote be kept for future installations? [y/n]: y
Required runtime for com.github.philip_scott.notes-up/x86_64/stable (runtime/org.gnome.Platform/x86_64/3.34) found in remote flathub
Do you want to install it? [y/n]: y
Installing in system:
org.gnome.Platform/x86_64/3.34                        flathub 12697f53c77f
org.gnome.Platform.Locale/x86_64/3.34                 flathub 0b2ef68ac418
org.freedesktop.Platform.GL.default/x86_64/19.08      flathub 8383da7a813b
org.freedesktop.Platform.GL.nvidia-435-21/x86_64/1.4  flathub b3571165bdd4
org.gtk.Gtk3theme.Adwaita-dark/x86_64/3.22            flathub 7c055bbc0667
org.freedesktop.Platform.VAAPI.Intel/x86_64/19.08     flathub 14ad39afcef6
org.freedesktop.Platform.openh264/x86_64/19.08        flathub 3e4c12dc2a37
com.github.philip_scott.notes-up/x86_64/stable        flathub eaa1997cafa5
  permissions: wayland, x11, dri
  file access: home
  dbus access: org.gtk.vfs, org.gtk.vfs.*
  dbus ownership: com.github.philip-scott.notes-up
com.github.philip_scott.notes_up.Locale/x86_64/stable flathub 34b62972b983
Is this ok [y/n]: y
Installing: org.gnome.Platform/x86_64/3.34 from flathub
[####################] 1175 metadata, 22208 content objects fetched; 297130 KiB transferred in 59 seconds
Now at 12697f53c77f.
Installing: org.gnome.Platform.Locale/x86_64/3.34 from flathub
[####################] 33 metadata, 164 content objects fetched; 4954 KiB transferred in 1 seconds
Now at 0b2ef68ac418.
Installing: org.freedesktop.Platform.GL.default/x86_64/19.08 from flathub
[####################] 30 metadata, 78 content objects fetched; 88756 KiB transferred in 3 seconds
Now at 8383da7a813b.
Installing: org.freedesktop.Platform.GL.nvidia-435-21/x86_64/1.4 from flathub
[####################] Downloading files: 11/11 103,3 MB (34,4 MB/s)        
Now at b3571165bdd4.
Installing: org.gtk.Gtk3theme.Adwaita-dark/x86_64/3.22 from flathub
[####################] 7 metadata, 5 content objects fetched; 2 KiB transferred in 0 seconds
Now at 7c055bbc0667.
Installing: org.freedesktop.Platform.VAAPI.Intel/x86_64/19.08 from flathub
[####################] 6 metadata, 11 content objects fetched; 8470 KiB transferred in 1 seconds
Now at 14ad39afcef6.
Installing: org.freedesktop.Platform.openh264/x86_64/19.08 from flathub
[####################] Downloading files: 6/6 594,2 kB (297,1 kB/s)          
Warning: Failed to install org.freedesktop.Platform.openh264/x86_64/19.08: While trying to apply extra data: runtime/org.freedesktop.Platform/x86_64/19.08 not installed
Installing: com.github.philip_scott.notes-up/x86_64/stable from flathub
[####################] 180 metadata, 3921 content objects fetched; 21577 KiB transferred in 10 seconds
Now at eaa1997cafa5.
Installing: com.github.philip_scott.notes_up.Locale/x86_64/stable from flathub
[####################] 9 metadata, 6 content objects fetched; 25 KiB transferred in 0 seconds
Now at 34b62972b983.
```

It looks like this command even installed a new Nvidia driver ! And I don't even find notes-up.

How to uninstall all what I installed with the flatpak command?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it safe to uninstall flatpak runtimes for apps I no longer have installed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1077052/is-it-safe-to-uninstall-flatpak-runtimes-for-apps-i-no-longer-have-installed)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not believe it was necessary for you to use `sudo` to install that.
In my case it wasn't.

List installed flatpak

```
flatpak list
```

```
    Ref                                              Options       
com.github.philip_scott.notes-up/x86_64/stable   system,current
org.freedesktop.Platform.GL.default/x86_64/19.08 system,runtime
org.gnome.Platform/x86_64/3.34                   system,runtime
```

To run app:

Type `notes-up` in Activities

or in Terminal:

```
flatpak run com.github.philip_scott.notes-up/x86_64/stable
```

Remove:

```
sudo flatpak uninstall com.github.philip_scott.notes-up/x86_64/stable
```

```
flatpak uninstall --unused
```

Repeat with all other unwanted paks

Or for ALL INSTALLED flatpak:

```
sudo flatpak uninstall --all
```